# How can I add associated domain for App Store? - app-ads.txt file for App Store Connect

Tags: android, ios, admob

As you know, Admob sent e-mails about app-ads.txt file to publishers. In e-mail, Admob said

> As such, we invite you to carefully review your app-ads.txt file if
>   you already have published one prior to the launch date. The file
>   should be published at the root directory of the website listed on
>   your Android Play Store or iOS App Store listing

In fact, I can successfully added new app-ads.txt file in my domain root file and for my Google Play apps, I can see green circle in my Admob panel.

[image: green light for Google Play apps]

On the other hand, for my iPhone app I can not find how to add my website to my App Store Listing page.

I added app-ads.txt file to my domain root but I do not know how can I relate this domain with my App Store App.

How can I relate my domain(url) with my App Store app? I could not find any area like

> website

or

> domain

in App Store Connect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I successfully apply Admob app-ads.txt file for App Store Connect.

The only thing you need to do

- Add ***Marketing URL*** to App Store Connect.

Go to App Store Connect

Ready for sale --> Marketing URL

I added and my Admob "app-ads.txt file found and verified"

Comment: I have added marketing url on App Store a week ago but still no success. None the less crawler successfully found the same url specified as a website on Google Play.

Comment: @gurkan stack I've also aded in the marketing url. I've checked the "Developer website", "Marketing url" and "Privacy policy". They are all okay, however in the Admob console it still says that the file doesn't exists.

Comment: I have no idea for developer website or privac policy. These are not subject of this question. 

I added only marketing URL and changed it. 1-2 week later text file was verified. 

Maybe you should wait..

Comment: FYI: after changing our Marketing URL it took **6 days** for AdMob to verify our app-ads.txt file

Answer (score 0):

App Store Listing has **support url**. you can place your domain same as playstore. but for support url change is require to resubmit.

App Store will not allow you to change support URL with same version. it will goes again for Review with new Review Guideline.

Comment: I have written Apple to suggest to allow editing the marketing url without resubmitting a new app bundle. Perhaps it is interesting if more people contact them for the same reason, so they see that it is something that affects more than one.

Comment: For App Store, the field to update is MARKETING url or SUPPORT url ?
I did update MARKETING url (and submitted a new app release) but it didn't work.
BTW, with Google Play the update was recognized the day after.

Comment: @pw2 did you found a solution for your problem?

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian yes, the correct field is MARKETING url, and you have to wait 4-5 days to get it recognized by Admob.

Comment: @pw2 - It looks like something went really bad on Admob's side. Initially when I added the content for the `app-adds.txt` (copied directly from Admob that they suggested) it worked for my Android apps but not for the iOS apps. Yesterday I re-checked the `app-adds.txt` and it has changed without a notification. I've re-copied the new content given by Admob and updated the file on my hosting. Everything is working now!

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian I'm facing same issue.. You say the app-ads.txt provided by admob has changed. May I know what has changed? I checked the admob console and didn't find any change yet still facing issue. Thanks

Comment: @Nana Ghartey the content of the "app-ads.txt" has changed on Admob side. I've checked the content of my "app-adds.txt" from the web server and what Admob gave to me. It changed with 1 single character in the ID after the "DIRECT" text. Again I copied the content from Admob then pasted again in my "app-adds.txt". After that everything worked (after 24h). Also, before making these changes a week before I've added the "Marketing URL" in the app store's console.

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian Okay, I've updated with the new app-ads.txt content from admob but on the ios side, I used the support url and not the marketing url. It's been a week and it's still not working. Should I change to marketing url?

Comment: @MartaRodriguez Only "promotional Text" is editable , so can we put some HTML code there. so that crawler take link from this field

Comment: @SurendraKumar Did you check if that really works? I don't think the crawler looks into every link of the app store.  Thanks!