# How to Connect the app-ads.txt file to my apps in the App Store and my paid website

Tags: admob, app-store-connect

How do I complete the [app-ads.txt process](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9363762#step2)? This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57795878/4833705) doesn't explain what to do. In step 3 from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57423789/4833705), it says `Create an app-ads.txt file in Notepad listing out all the lines you received, and save.` But which lines am I supposed to add?

I have no idea what to do beyond steps 6, 7, and 8 to complete the `app-ads.txt` process. In step 6 there is a `publisher url` and a `goole code snippet` from step 5. I don't know what to do with either of those.

Process so far:

1- I have 5 iOS apps on the AppStore.

2- In AppStore Connect, all 5 of my apps have the same website and marketing url:

[image]

3- 4 of the apps all contain banner and interstitial ads

4- I have all of the App IDs correctly setup from AdMob and connected to all 4 apps

5- In the AdMob console I pressed SET UP APP-ADS.TXT

[image]

and I copied the code snippet which looks something like

```
google.com, pub-1234567890, DIRECT, abc123xyz456
```

6- I created an account at https://www.app-ads-txt.com/ and pasted the above code snippet inside of there. The page now looks like:

[image]

7. I have my own paid website. I added an `app-ads.txt` page as in *[www.flowtinc.com/app-ads.txt](http://www.flowtinc.com/app-ads.txt)*. All I did was add the page, I didn't add anything else because I don't know what to do from there
8. In the AdMob console, I went to the `app-ads.txt` page and it says *we've crawled the following urls* ... **No app-ads.txt file found**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the website you are using can be risky cause they also add their publisher id below the content of the app-ads file. So in order to achieve this, I would recommend using blogger and follow below steps:

1. Create a blog on https://www.blogger.com/
2. Click on **settings** and Then go under the **Monetization** option, Switch on enable custom ads.txt there.
3. Then remaining in settings, go to the **Error and Redirects** option, Click custom redirects, and then add the following in the coming input dialogue:

   From: /app-ads.txt To: /ads.txt Permanent: Yes

   click save that's it.
4. Now for adding content of your app-ads.txt, go to the **Monetization** option and click on custom ads.txt, add content here and press save.
5. Now you can check the access of the app-ads.txt file by using: https://your-blogspot-name.blogspot.com/app-ads.txt

Answer (score 0):

After following the [steps](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9363762) to create your `app-ads.txt` file, it should look like something this:

```
google.com, pub-1234567890, DIRECT, abc123xyz456.
```

You simply paste that 1 line into Sublime or Notepad or any text editor and then save it as `app-ads.txt`.

If this is your first time doing this and you are only using AdMob it should only be the 1 line above. If you are using other ad sellers, then you will have to create a separate line for them in them in the `app-ads.txt` file. Here is some more info from [Vungle](https://support.vungle.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029177591--Vungle-app-ads-txt-entries#step-2-reach-out-to-all-ad-sources-direct-resellers-etc--0-6) on how to do that

Next you need to upload the `app-ads.txt` to the **root** directory of **your website**. You can follow these 2 videos on how to do that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWapRTV6GAkand https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OgSbxNO46wQ.

If you are using IONOS and using their Website Builder Service, you will not be able to upload the `app-ads.txt` file to root directly. Call them and they will have to upload it for you. You will have to email them your `app-ads.txt` file.